# How to look for a node by id in the Perl Graph.pm module?

Tags: perl, graph

I'm trying to use the [Graph.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph) module but all the examples I saw are keeping simple basic scalars as nodes. I'm trying to keep instances of three different classes as nodes in that graph. Consider:

```
sub new {
    my ($class,$node_name) = @_;
    my $self = {
        "name"  => $node_name,
        # More fields
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Now I can do something like:

```
$g->add_vertex(new DNode("/"));
```

where `DNode` is the constructor of **one** of the three classes. But how can I can look for that node? For example, I have:

```
$g->add_vertex(new DNode("/"));
$g->add_vertex(new DNode("/a"));
$g->add_vertex(new DNode("/a/b"));
my $node = $g->get_vertex("/a/b");
```

There is no `get_vertex`. I thought that `add_vertex_by_id` can be helpful here:

```
$g->add_vertex_by_id(new DNode("/"),"/");
$g->add_vertex_by_id(new DNode("/a"),"/a");
$g->add_vertex_by_id(new DNode("/a/b"),"/a/b");
```

But there is no `get_vertex_by_id` method. How can I do the lookup?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can actually use objects as vertices and that the references aren't just stringified? Might work better if you store the objects in the attributes of the vertex instead.

Comment: It's possible but tricky to retrieve directly. See my answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you're really trying to achieve. I can try to explain the things you did ask about (I'm the module's current maintainer).

The Graph module is about things, and connections between things. The usual approach, which I think will work for you here, is to identify "things" (vertices) by string names, such as "/" or "/a", and set an attribute (e.g. `object`) as the Perl object. You can instead have the vertices identified by actual Perl objects, using [`refvertexed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph#refvertexed).

Once you've added a vertex, like this:

```perl
$g = Graph->new;
$g->set_vertex_attribute('/a', object => $node_class->new('/a')); # no need to separately add vertex
```

You can look it up:

```perl
$bool = $g->has_vertex('/a');
$obj = $g->get_vertex_attribute('/a', 'object'); # safely returns undef if no such vertex, or attribute not set
```

The `by_id` methods are part of [Multiedges, Multivertices, Multigraphs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph#Multiedges,-Multivertices,-Multigraphs), where you'd have several (or "multi") "aspects" of the same vertex, each identified by an ID. I don't think that's what you want here.

If this doesn't solve your problem, you'd need to explain your problem more/better :-)